# meta Physics, not Physics meta

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

The first thing that I noticed about *this* site was the irony of its name. Surely I'm not the only one who would rather have the logo look like this:

[image: meta Physics, not Physics meta]

(I guess this is a meta.meta.physics question.)

Comment: This implies that this site is about philosophy, which it is certainly not.

Comment: @stafusa:  *of it's name* → *of its name*   (its = possessive, it's = "it is" or "it has". See for example *[How to Use Its and It's](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Its-and-It%27s)*.)

Comment: Hi @PeterMortensen, I know that. Please notice that I'm not the author of the post. It also turned out that small corrections, like the one I did with the period/parenthesis and the one you're pointing out now, are actually not recommended (for old posts), since that makes them "active" unjustifiably.

Comment: Well, you did make it active so I'll further revive it with a comment: Though “silly” questions are frowned on here in Metaland, I can still point out that the https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta link _still_ says “**Meta Physics** Stack Exchange is the part of the site where...” Drawing attention to this was, of course, the point of the original question (though perhaps my extremely dry sense of humor is lost on other metazens). In other words, the about text should be changed from Meta Physics to Physics Meta.

Comment: @Seth Your link there shows something completely different than what this meta question asks.  That actually does seem to be a valid thing to change.

Answer (score 9):

Disagree. From talking to users new to the Stack Exchange system, one of the things that confuses them the most is the purpose of the Meta complement site to each Stack Exchange site. Having these new users come to the Physics site, see the meta button at the top, click it, and then see metaphysics as the banner would confuse them even more.

Comment: Point taken (assuming that a non-programmer people know what "meta" implies). However, aside from the wonderful irony, the link to this site **already** says "meta.physics is the place to talk about things ... ".

Comment: But it would be so delicious!